# How to I permanently revert to the old view in Jira?

Tags: jira

**How to I permanently revert to the old view in Jira?**

With the recent Web Jira update, all the old UI have been changed, few functionalities are missing in new UI/UX updates which am not comfortable with  , so How to switch back to old view permanently?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable  view for now by going to your Profile picture >  Settings > New Jira issue view and disable it.
[disable option image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dJx7.jpg)